# С помощью какого суффикса образованы данные слова?

Tags: словообразование

***Международник, скромник, труженик, путаник.***

Правильно ли сформулирован вопрос в задании:

> С помощью **какого суффикса** образованы данные слова?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ДЗ

Comment: _behemothus: …потому что ДЗ_ === Так-то оно так… Но правильно ли сформулирован вопрос в учебнике? Прочитайте: _"С помощью **какого суффикса**?.."_  Какой бы суффикс нашли Вы, сопоставляя приведённые в задании слова? Суффикс **-ник**? На мой взгляд, сама постановка вопроса в учебнике неверна и может только запутать учащихся. Ведь и по Ефремовой, и по Тихонову эти слова общего суффикса не имеют.

Comment: А почему нельзя спрашивать ДЗ??? В классе возникли разногласия, в словарях тоже нет единого мнения, поэтому и обратились к вам... Про постановку вопроса согласна...

Comment: irina19, это стандартная формулировка. Здесь обычно не делают домашние задания, чтобы не приучать учащихся паразитировать. Если человек начал делать - и столкнулся с трудностями, обычно требуется просто разъяснить, в чем он видит трудность. Ну или в  Вашем случае, я бы просто изложила точку зрения каждой из стороню

Comment: slava1947, думаю, что первопричина обращения сюда за консультацией не в некорректной формулировке. Надо трактовать как "с помощью каких суффиксов" или "с помощью какого суффикса образовано **каждое** из следующих слов".

Comment: _IrinaGL:  Надо трактовать как "с помощью каких суффиксов" или "с помощью какого суффикса образовано каждое из следующих слов"._ === Ха-ха...  То есть к самой формулировке в учебнике (см. http://bib.social/russkiy-yazyik/osnovnyie-sposobyi-obrazovaniya-39857.html ) у Вас претензий нет? Вы эту формулировку считаете корректной?

Answer (score 1):

> С помощью **какого суффикса** образованы данные слова?

На мой взгляд, такая формулировка неверна. И по Ефремовой, и по Тихонову эти слова общего суффикса не имеют.

**См. возможный разбор:**

МЕЖДУНАРОДНИК -- специалист по вопросам международной политики, международного права;

***международн***ый -> международн-**[ик](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136143)**.

===

СКРОМНИК -- человек скромного поведения;

***скромн***ый ->  скромн-**[ик](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136143)**.

===

ПУТАНИК -- тот, кто плохо разбирается в чём-л., путает себя и других;

***пута***ть ->  пута-**[ник](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136341)**.

===

ТРУЖЕНИК -- тот, кто много и усердно трудится;

***труд***иться -> труж-**[еник](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136026)**.

===

**P.S.**

Но возможен и иной подход к словообразованию  *труженика* (так у Тихонова):

***труд***иться -> труж-**е/ник** (суффикс ***-ник*** + интерфикс ***-е-***).

Answer (score 1):

Есть и другой взгляд.

Пут/а/н/ик-тот, кто даёт путаный ответ- суфф. -ик

труж/еник - от устаревшего прилагательного труж/ен/ый, а -еник=ен +ик, так что вполне возможен ответ, что в своём начале слово образовалось с помощью суфф. -ик, а сейчас произошло слияние двух суффиксов в один.

И получается, что вполне корректный вопрос и ответ на него:все слова образовались  с помощью суфф. -ИК

Comment: Гм… То, что в _путанике_ возможно выделение суффикса _-ик_, я видел, но вот чтоб в _труженике -ик_? Когда-то в этом слове действительно выделялся суффикс _-икъ_, но чтоб сейчас?..  И в словаре Панова с Текучевым суффикс _-еник_, а не _-ик_, хоть эти авторы и пишут, что исторически _труженик_ произошло от _труженый_.  Людмила, Ваша версия мне нравится. Смущает только, что у Тихонова ни в _труженике_, ни в _путанике_ нет суффикса _-ик_, а ведь авторы учебника предлагают учащимся использовать именно его словарь.

Comment: Я же оговорилась, что еник=ен+ик. На сложные(составные) суфф. тоже разный взгляд. Кто-то не признаёт суфф.-еник, только ен+ик.Может, в задании и имели в виду именно момент образования слова, а тогда это были отдельные суффиксы труженый-тружен/ик.Это же только сейчас появился -еник